# Use the Datagrid component with custom queries - react-admin

Tags: react-admin

Receive below errors, when using Datagrid component with custom queries.  Below code works with **react-admin** ver 3.3.1, whereas it doesn't work with ver 3.8.1

**TypeError:** Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

**Browser's console info:** List components must be used inside a <ListContext.Provider>. Relying on props rather than context to get List data and callbacks is deprecated and won't be supported in the next major version of react-admin.

Refer: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html
#Tip: You can use the Datagrid component with custom queries:

````
import keyBy from 'lodash/keyBy'
import { useQuery, Datagrid, TextField, Pagination, Loading } from 'react-admin'

const CustomList = () => {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const perPage = 50;
    const { data, total, loading, error } = useQuery({
        type: 'GET_LIST',
        resource: 'posts',
        payload: {
            pagination: { page, perPage },
            sort: { field: 'id', order: 'ASC' },
            filter: {},
        }
    });

    if (loading) {
        return <Loading />
    }
    if (error) {
        return <p>ERROR: {error}</p>
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Datagrid
                data={keyBy(data, 'id')}
                ids={data.map(({ id }) => id)}
                currentSort={{ field: 'id', order: 'ASC' }}
                basePath="/posts" // required only if you set use "rowClick"
                rowClick="edit"
            >
                <TextField source="id" />
                <TextField source="name" />
            </Datagrid>
            <Pagination
                page={page}
                perPage={perPage}
                setPage={setPage}
                total={total}
            />
        </>
    )
} ```

Please help!
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since react-admin 3.7, `<Datagrid>` and `<Pagination>` read data from a `ListContext`, instead of expecting the data to be injected by props. See for instance the updated `<Datagrid>` docs at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#the-datagrid-component.

Your code will work if you wrap it in a `<ListContextProvider>`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import keyBy from 'lodash/keyBy'
import { useQuery, Datagrid, TextField, Pagination, Loading, ListContextProvider } from 'react-admin'

export const CustomList = () => {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const perPage = 50;
    const { data, total, loading, error } = useQuery({
        type: 'GET_LIST',
        resource: 'posts',
        payload: {
            pagination: { page, perPage },
            sort: { field: 'id', order: 'ASC' },
            filter: {},
        }
    });

    if (loading) {
        return <Loading />
    }
    if (error) {
        return <p>ERROR: {error}</p>
    }
    return (
        <ListContextProvider value={{
                data: keyBy(data, 'id'),
                ids: data.map(({ id }) => id),
                total,
                page,
                perPage,
                setPage,
                currentSort: { field: 'id', order: 'ASC' },
                basePath: "/posts",
                resource: 'posts',
                selectedIds: []
        }}>
            <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
                <TextField source="id" />
                <TextField source="name" />
            </Datagrid>
            <Pagination />
        </ListContextProvider >
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I exactly did as you mentioned but faced an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined`. it's when it looks for currentSort.field at `Datagrid (Datagrid.js:79)`. any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I think I  solved my problem. It seems `resource` and `selectedIds` are required for this to work!

Comment: @François Zaninotto, is there some reason why the documentation hasn't been updated? Almost 2 years later the section "Rendering <Datagrid> With A Custom Query" at the bottom of the page still has incorrect code, and there are no examples of how to do this properly.

Comment: I see 2 reasons: 1/ Nobody ever opened an issue about it in the GitHub repository (I just did it: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/7371) 2/ This is an open-source project. If you need something to be changed, the best way to make it happen is to open a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

`<ReferenceManyField>`, as well as other relationship-related components, also implement a ListContext. That means you can use a `<Datagrid>` of a `<Pagination>` inside this component.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#uselistcontext

Your code should look like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import keyBy from 'lodash/keyBy'
import { useQuery, Datagrid, TextField, Pagination, Loading, ListContextProvider } from 'react-admin'

export const CustomList = () => {
   
    return (
       <ReferenceManyField reference="Your resource for pull the data" target="linked field">
            <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
                <TextField source="id" />
                <TextField source="name" />
            </Datagrid>
        </ReferenceManyField>
    )
}
```